# Flutter firebase firestore update value if contain "." => fail

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

```
print(hoursRanges[selectedHourRangeIndex!]);
//output: 09.00 - 11.00
```

it separates the dots when I want to update the value

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection("staff")
.doc(data.email)
.collection("archive)
.doc(inputs.date.substring(0.10))
.update({
"${hoursRanges[selectedRangeIndex!]}": true});
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: Hi @BerkeUğur, is it possible to share your Firestore document structure?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4s7a.png)

its my firestore document structure
I solved it by changing it like this 09.00 - 11.00 => 09:00 - 11:00